# Отглагольное прилагательное или причастие, сколько Н в суффиксе, слитно или раздельно с НЕ?

Tags: прилагательные

Дано словосочетание: давно н(..)краше..ые стены.
Это причастие или отглагольное прилагательное, сколько Н в суффиксе, слитно или раздельно пишется с НЕ?
Правильно ли я напишу: давно некрашеные стены (слитно с НЕ и с одним Н)?

Заранее большое спасибо за ответ! :)

Comment: Конечно, причастие. С прилагательным нельзя сказать «давно»: _давно красные/желтые стены_.

Comment: @SergeySlepov как это нельзя «давно» с прилагательным? В [корпусе](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=Давно&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=semx&morph1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=A%2Cplen&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=semx&morph2=) полно примеров: давно знакомый, привычный, готовый…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Это причастие или отглагольное прилагательное

It's a participle. It is a part of a participial phrase (*причастный оборот*) and governs a modifier.

> сколько Н в суффиксе, слитно или раздельно пишется с НЕ?

*давно не крашенные стены*

Rosenthal et al., *Справочник по русскому языку*, § 48.1:

> В суффиксах страдательных причастий прошедшего времени пишется нн; как правило, эти причастия имеют приставки или пояснительные слова: исправленная рукопись; правленные корректором гранки.

Comment: thank you :))
Am I right in thinking that word '**золоченая** вещь' is a verbal adjectives (по-русски отглагольное прилагательное, I am not sure if I called it correctly in English :))

Comment: @A.V. yes, it's a deverbal adjective.

Comment: Thank you! :)))